# How do I input double quotes?

Tags: vbscript

In VBS, I want to make something like this:

```
Name=inputbox("You wake up. You are on an island. You don't remember how you got here. In       
fact, you don't even remember your name. What is your name?")
fname=inputbox("Ah, yes. My name is " &Name ". I remember now.")
```

How would I do that? Can I not use an  *&Name*  in the middle?

Comment: Search the documentation for "Escaping quotes"

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there. You need to use the concatenation operator, `&`, on both sides of the variable:

```
fname = inputbox("Ah, yes. My name is " & Name & ". I remember now.")
```

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are getting at regarding the quotes. If you want to include a double quote in a string then you need to escape it by writing `""`. So the way to create a string with just a single character that is a double quote is like this `""""`.

Comment: `""""` (4 double quotes, not 5). Or you could use `Chr(34)`.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if you want to keep your code similar to that of VB.Net/C#, you could possibly do something like:

```
fname = inputbox(Replace("Ah, yes. My name is {0}. I remember now.", "{0}", Name))
```

Just my $0.02 on the subject.  That would allow you to read it like the newer stuff, but using the older function(s).

Comment: Protip, use COM objects like the StringBuilder class: `CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder").AppendFormat("Ah, yes. My name is {0}. I remember now.", "Dory").ToString()`